# Issue with UIControlEventTouchDragOutside implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

I have a 2-d button array in my main view and want to be able to move them by dragging inside this view. The buttons are pretty narrow, around 23x23 pixels. I have added targets for control events `touchDragExit` and `touchDragOutside` but they were fired many pixels after I moved my finger outside the button. Hence I subclassed `UIButton` and overrode `continueTrackingWithTouch` with some code I found in SO. Notice I don't call the superclass implementation.

```
-(BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGFloat boundsExtension = 5.0f;
    CGRect outerBounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -1 * boundsExtension, -1 * boundsExtension);

    BOOL touchOutside = !CGRectContainsPoint(outerBounds, [touch locationInView:self]);
    if(touchOutside)
    {
        BOOL previousTouchInside = CGRectContainsPoint(outerBounds, [touch previousLocationInView:self]);
        if(previousTouchInside)
        {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
        }
        else
        {
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
        }
    }
    return self.tracking;
}
```

Both events are fired correctly but my `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` action receives wrong touch info when its action is called. Here is the first part of my implementation:

```
-(void) dragOutside:(UIButton *) sender withEvents:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint relativeLocToInitialCell = [touch locationInView:sender];

    NSLog(@"Translation %f %f NumTouch %d",relativeLocToInitialCell.x, relativeLocToInitialCell.y, [[event allTouches] count]);
    ...   
}
```

`[[event allTouches] count]` still returns 0 until I move my finger much away from the button. Then of course `relativeLocToInitialCell` fields `x` and `y` are both 0, which are the values I use for later computations. Any idea what might be the problem?

EDIT: A deleted answer suggested using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead of touchdrag events, but I couldn't use it because it was firing too rapidly before handling one event I got another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up having to handle also `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` event. Though this looks a workaround, thinking on the fundamentals of these touch drag events makes it a reasonable solution. All drag events are sourced from `touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded` . Apple added some threshold before `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` is sent, but up until that threshold `UIControlEventTouchDragInside` event is certainly sent.

My solution was to remove overridden `continueTrackingWithTouch` method and go on with its default implementation. Then I handled both inside and outside events, and moved my initialization code from exit event to inside event, and added control statements in inside event. Abstracted code looks like below:

```
-(void) dragInside:(UIButton *) sender withEvents:(UIEvent *) event
{
    if(stillInsideOriginalControl) return;

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint relativeLocToInitialCell = [touch locationInView:sender];

    [self processTouch];
}

-(void) dragOutside:(UIButton *) sender withEvents:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint relativeLocToInitialCell = [touch locationInView:sender];

    [self processTouch];
}
```